# Add SQL Replication Bundle to existing database?

Tags: ravendb

I have a database with data I would like to replicate to a SQL server.  I am aware that I can add *RavenDB replication* after the fact in the Settings menu. 
 However, I don't find any setting for adding the **SQL Replication** bundle except during database creation (see image below).

Would it be best to create a new database with SQL replication enabled then replicate my old database to that one?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the Studio screenshot I assume RavenDB version 3.0/3.5
(in the upcoming version 4.0 this most likely would be handled differently)

Creating a new database with SQL replication bundle enabled, then replicating to the new database would work.

There is another option - simply add "SqlReplication" to key "Raven/ActiveBundles" in the database document. Then, cause the database to reload (disable then enable the database).

Like this:
[image: screenshot of the Studio with Sql replication bundle enabled]